# MS SQL Linked Database Automated/Scripted Query

Tags: sql-server

I have a linked database in MS SQL Server management Studio.  I can query it and get the exact data I need in the format I need with headers and all.

I need a way to automate this query on a schedule and export as a csv automatically.

Currently my process is to open the query in MS SQL SMS, and run the query (which mind you takes 15 minutes to run) and then in the results area right click and "save results as"

I would like to either automate it with in SMS, or be able to script it.  What's confusing to me is how to write a script for a linked database.

I noticed that when you right click on the Linked Server there are a couple of options to script.  For example, there's "Create To", "DROP To", and "DROP And CREATE To".  Each of the scripts seem to be formated in a similar way with the following:

```
USE [master]
GO

/****** Object:  LinkedServer [QREMOTE]    Script Date: 2/24/2022 10:59:26 AM ******/
EXEC master.dbo.sp_dropserver @server=N'QREMOTE', @droplogins='droplogins'
GO
```

I'm not familiar with this scripting and I'm not sure how to use it.  Any assistance would be appreciated!

Some background, this is a quickbooks database connected through the QODBC driver in which I'm using SMS to query specific fields from a table that need to be exported in a specific order so they can be imported into another system.

Comment: Why do you need to script the creation of the linked server? Surely once you've created it, you can just use that one each time you need it. As for what you're asking, it's pretty broad; just asking for assistance isn't a question and [so] isn't a free consultancy service.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I guess I wasn't very clear in what I was asking.

I don't understand how to utilize MS SQL SMS to automate a query I have.  Do I create a script that runs via Task Scheduler and utilize MS SQL commands, or do I use SMS to somehow schedule the task.

If Stack Overflow is not built for providing advice on this matter, I apologize.  I've done 85% of the work to get the information I need, but I need a direction for the last 15%.

Comment: Automation is usually done using SQL Server Agent. You've also tagged `smsmanager` but your question doesn't seem to be about SMS operations in Android apps.

Comment: Sorry about that, I removed the tag.  I guess I miss understood that as well.

Thank you for your insight, this may be a missing piece to my puzzle.  I'm very new to mysql and SQL, so I'm learning.